# in Java 8, how to serialize/deserialize a date time information with time zone

Tags: json, datetime, jackson

I would like to deserilize a json string with datetime information such as 2016-07-22T11:20:48.430-07:00 to a date time object using Jackson, currently, I am using joda Datetime, it works fine, I was able to convert 2016-07-22T11:20:48.430-07:00 to Datetime (UTC).

However, I want to use java 8 date time object, any recommendation? localDateTime do not have time zone information, and zoneDateTime seems not be able to deal with format like: 2016-07-22T11:20:48.430-07:00

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310

Comment: Terminology: that input has an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) not a time zone. A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Answer (score 1):

## `OffsetDateTime`

Your input strings have an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) not a time zone. A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

For date-time values with an offset, use the aptly named [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2016-07-22T11:20:48.430-07:00" );
```

You can apply a full time zone if desired.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZone( zoneId );
```

For UTC value, extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
```

## Adapter library

I don't use Jackson myself but I know you can use various adapter classes to handle java.time classes. See the first comment on the Question for one. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17491143/642706) on a similar Question for another.

Hopefully Jackson will eventually be modernized to handle these types directly.